# Coding standard with multiple if condition

Tags: java

I need to set data in entity based on on some condition.

I have used below to set data

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getGender())) {
    mstCustomer.setGender(customerVO.getGender());
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getBirthDate())) {
    mstCustomer.setDob(DateUtils.getUtilDate(customerVO.getBirthDate()));
}

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getAdd1())) {
    mstCustomer.setAddress1(customerVO.getAdd1());
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getAdd2())) {
    mstCustomer.setAddress2(customerVO.getAdd2());
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getAdd3())) {
    mstCustomer.setAddress3(customerVO.getAdd3());
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getPincode())) {
    mstCustomer.setPinCode(customerVO.getPincode());
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getStateName())) {
    MstState state = mstStateRepository.findByName(customerVO.getStateName());
    mstCustomer.setMstState(state);
}

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getCity())) {
    MstCity city = mstCityRepository.findByName(customerVO.getCity());
    mstCustomer.setMstCity(city);
}

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getIdentificationType())) {
    mstCustomer.setIdentificationType(customerVO.getIdentificationType());
}

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getIdentificationData())) {
    mstCustomer.setIdentificationData(customerVO.getIdentificationData());
}

MstStatus mstStatus = mstStatusRepository.findOne(MstStatusEnum.CUST_ACTIVE.getStatusCode());
if (mstStatus != null) {
    mstCustomer.setMstStatus(mstStatus);
}

if (!StringUtils.isBlank(customerVO.getMaritalStatus())) {
    mstCustomer.setMaritalStatus(customerVO.getMaritalStatus());
}
if (StringUtils.isBlank(customerVO.getWeddingAnniversary())) {
    mstCustomer.setWeddingAnniversary(DateUtils.getDateFromString(customerVO.getWeddingAnniversary()));
}

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getMotherTongue())) {
    mstCustomer.setMotherTongue(customerVO.getMotherTongue());
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getFamilySize())) {
    mstCustomer.setFamilySize(Integer.valueOf(customerVO.getFamilySize()));
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getAdultsSize())) {
    mstCustomer.setAdultsSize(Integer.valueOf(customerVO.getAdultsSize()));
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getNoOfKids())) {
    mstCustomer.setNoOfKids(Integer.valueOf(customerVO.getNoOfKids()));
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getChilddob1())) {
    mstCustomer.setChilddob1(DateUtils.getDateFromString(customerVO.getChilddob1()));
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getChilddob2())) {
    mstCustomer.setChilddob2(DateUtils.getDateFromString(customerVO.getChilddob2()));
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getProfession())) {
    mstCustomer.setProfession(customerVO.getProfession());
}
```

But sonar throwing this exception : `Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 27 to the 15 allowed.`

Please suggest what is the best way to refactor above code.

Comment: try just validating your fields inside their respective setters .

Comment: The code is clean and legitimate, disable Sonar.

Comment: @YvesDaoust there's a very large amount of duplication in this code though. There's a lot of room for mistakes (for example check if the birth date is not blank but then use the middle name to set the birth date)

Comment: @Dici: I can't see a single duplication here. Every statement addresses a different field and you can't avoid the exhaustive enumeration. You can avoid the double call to the getters by assigning temporary variables, but this wouldn't make the code much clearer. The solution by AxelM (which I like) would remove all complexity in this function, at the expense of more code.

Comment: The structure is very repetitive, there is clear repetition in this code. Using lambdas is one way to only keep useful information. Lambdas also allow reducing boilerplate to the strict minimum.

Comment: @Dici: it is repetitive in the sense that it is a sequence of assignments. You can't compress that sequence. Lambdas will not shorten it.

Comment: Haha, if you say so. I believe using lambdas compresses this code by a factor of roughly 3x lines and 2x characters without hurting readability (actually it probably improves it by reducing noise). See below.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the original code is much easier to understand than the lambda version.

Comment: @jick I guess it's a matter of taste. As a strong advocate against repetition in code I don't share this feeling. What this code is doing is not rocket science, so whether it is going to be readable or not mostly depends on how fast the eye can parse it, but it won't get any more complicated to understand however you write it.

Comment: I was shocked by this code **before** I realised half of it was hidden! It is wearying to read so much similar code. You need to check that the methods in both parentheses match every time, leading to mental ennui due to scanning repetitive code, which means this code is more likely to house mistakes. The message about excessive cognitive complexity is spot on. You also have to make sure that each object is being used correctly each time (are `customerVO` and `mstCustomer` the same type?). I don't know Java well enough to suggest any improvements, but I'd know them when I see them!

Comment: Mark it as "generated code" so Sonar won't complain. You don't write code like this by hand, because its very nature is being redious and repetitive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code *does* work and code refactor might be more suitable for [codereview.se].

Comment: @AndrewT. I think it's reasonable. It's much less, "how is my code" and much more "how can I fix this (sonar) issue".

Comment: you just making a **God Class or Long Method Code Smells** with gathering all IFs in one place. @Axel M 's answer is the correct refactoring technique.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems pretty doable using lambdas:

```
private void setIfNotBlank(String value, Consumer<String> setter)  {
    setConditionally(value, setter, StringUtils::isNotBlank);
}

// if you don't need non-string arguments you can inline this method
private <T> void setConditionally(T value, Consumer<T> setter, Predicate<T> shouldSet) {
    if (shouldSet.test(value)) setter.accept(value);
}
```

Then,

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getBirthDate())) {
    mstCustomer.setDob(DateUtils.getUtilDate(customerVO.getBirthDate()));
}

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getCity())) { 
    MstCity city = mstCityRepository.findByName(customerVO.getCity()); 
    mstCustomer.setMstCity(city); 
}
```

would become

```
setIfNotBlank(customerVO.getBirthDate(), birthDate -> mstCustomer.setDob(DateUtils.getUtilDate(birthDate)));
setIfNotBlank(customerVO.getCity(), cityName -> { 
    MstCity city = mstCityRepository.findByName(cityName); 
    mstCustomer.setMstCity(city); 
});
```

Comment: if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getCity())) {
   MstCity city = mstCityRepository.findByName(customerVO.getCity());
   mstCustomer.setMstCity(city);
  } and if (messageVO.getFlag().equals(CommonConstants.CUSTOMER_HUB_CREATE_UPDATE_SUCCESS)) {
   mstCustomer.setCustomerId(messageVO.getCustomerId());
  } Can you please help me how to convert above both condition setIfNotBlank to call this method?

Comment: I updated my answer to contain your first example. The second one doesn't follow the same pattern as other setters, I think you could simply leave it as it is

Comment: No worries. I would advise you to at least look at John Kugelman's answer because I find it pretty good as well, it could teach you something. He definitely deserves your upvote.

Answer (score 16):

This is perfect for [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). First, make a helper method to convert each of the possibly-blank fields to an `Optional<String>`.

```
Optional<String> optional(String value) {
    return StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)
        ? Optional.of(value)
        : Optional.empty();
}
```

Then, rewrite the code like so:

```
optional(customerVO.getGender())   .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setGender);
optional(customerVO.getBirthDate()).map(DateUtils::getUtilDate)
                                   .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setDob);

optional(customerVO.getAdd1())     .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setAddress1);
optional(customerVO.getAdd2())     .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setAddress2);
optional(customerVO.getAdd3())     .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setAddress3);
optional(customerVO.getPincode())  .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setPinCode);
optional(customerVO.getStateName()).map(mstStateRepository::findByName)
                                   .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setMstState);

optional(customerVO.getCity())     .map(mstCityRepository::findByName)
                                   .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setMstCity);

optional(customerVO.getIdentificationType()).ifPresent(mstCustomer::setIdentificationType);
optional(customerVO.getIdentificationData()).ifPresent(mstCustomer::setIdentificationData);

Optional.of(MstStatusEnum.CUST_ACTIVE.getStatusCode())
    .map(mstStatusRepository::findOne)
    .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setMstStatus);

optional(customerVO.getMaritalStatus())     .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setMaritalStatus);
optional(customerVO.getWeddingAnniversary()).map(DateUtils::getDateFromString)
                                            .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setWeddingAnniversary);

optional(customerVO.getMotherTongue()).ifPresent(mstCustomer::setMotherTongue);
optional(customerVO.getFamilySize())  .map(Integer::valueOf).ifPresent(mstCustomer::setFamilySize);
optional(customerVO.getAdultsSize())  .map(Integer::valueOf).ifPresent(mstCustomer::setAdultsSize);
optional(customerVO.getNoOfKids())    .map(Integer::valueOf).ifPresent(mstCustomer::setNoOfKids);
optional(customerVO.getChilddob1())   .map(DateUtils::getDateFromString).ifPresent(mstCustomer::setChilddob1);
optional(customerVO.getChilddob2())   .map(DateUtils::getDateFromString).ifPresent(mstCustomer::setChilddob2);
optional(customerVO.getProfession())  .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setProfession);
```

`ifPresent` calls the named function only if the field is non-blank. `map` helps convert the values from one type to another. Notice how this helps flatten the logic so the mappings are separate from the settings.

Comment: +1, it's a bit neater than my suggestion, especially for the fields which require lots of transformations before being set. It becomes a bit less scalable than mine if you have many different implementations of `optionalField` (but could be fixed with a small refactor)

Comment: I like using `Optional` for this and have one constructive comment regarding formatting: the vertical alignment of the method calls might do more harm than good in the long run. If you rename, for example, `getMotherTongue()` to `getFirstLanguage()`, the alignment of that line is broken. If you do the renaming in a different class via your IDEs refactoring tool, you won't even notice. If you change method names often (which can be a good idea), you'll either have to constantly adjust the alignment or it'll degrade to look very messy over time.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, this code fundamentally can't be improved. By its very nature, it is tedious and repetitive. It translates properties of one object into properties of another object and Java simply doesn't provide a short and concise way to express it.

Consider other answers: they turn a single if-statement of your original code into some another statement, so instead of 20 `if`s you end up with 20 `optional()` calls or 20 `setIfNotBlank()` calls — but the main problem of your code is that there are 20 long, similar-looking statements, so they don't improve much, you still end with 20 long, similar-looking statements in one method.

You can turn to reflection: invent some annotations and annotate the classes of `customerVO` and `mstCustomer` objects with them, then re-write this method in the veins of "For each annotation on the first object, find the corresponding annotation on the second object, perform assignment". But now instead 20 long, similar-looking `if`-statements you have 40 long, similar-looking annotations, and they're in two different files. That's even worse, so if you chose to go this way, try to annotate only one of the classes and not both of them: then you'll end with only 20 annotations so things are as bad as they were before.

You can turn to code generation: invent some simple properties description format (or find an existing one), write a small tool that will take this description and will produce the code for the classes of `customerVO` and `mstCustomer` objects. Now instead of 20 long, similar-looking `if`-statements you have 20 hopefully short, maybe not so similar-looking property descriptions in a language only you know and an additional tool in the build chain.

As you can see, you just can't escape writing 20 long boring similar-looking things.

So my answer would be: don't refactor it. Mark this code, and the classes of `customerVO` and `mstCustomer` objects, as connected and make sure to always change them in sync. That doesn't mean writing some unit tests for it — although you should do this too — that means establishing a procedure. This is no longer a technical problem: it's a persons' problem. Tell to other developers about this piece of code; write comments "Don't forget to check other parts" in this code; review the commits with the changes in those parts of the code. You can't rely on automation tools to keep this code correct, so you and your colleagues have to remember to do it manually.

Comment: This is the real answer. Static code analysis is an aid not a goal and sometimes you need to mark it as intended behavior. Transformation code simply is repetitive and other than addressing its subjective elegance, you can't do much about it.

Comment: I disagree with you in two ways. Firstly, I don't believe there is no technological answer that would eliminate all of this boilerplate. Some frameworks have been successful at reducing boilerplate using annotations and compiler plugins, and there's nothing fundamentally different about the OP's use case. Secondly, if such solutions are not implemented yet or can't be used for whatever reason, it is always valuable to make the code less error-prone (see my comment on OP's question) and reduce the noise to help developers read/debug it (even in such simple code there could be wiring bugs)

Comment: See @meriton's answer for a living proof this code is highly error-prone.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to solve this issue, would propably by writing setters for all those assignments.

Like:

```
private void setGender(GenderObject customerVO){
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getGender())) {
        this.setGender(customerVO.getGender());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you may invoke the setter either way, you could simplify the code by factoring the null handling into reusable conversion methods:

```
mstCustomer.setGender(parseString(customerVO.getGender());
mstCustomer.setDob(parseDate(customerVO.getDob());
...
```

where

```
String parseString(String s) {
    return StringUtils.isBlank(s) ? null : s;
}
```

and so on.

Irrespective of the approach you choose, eliminating the redundant conditionals will be a boon to maintainability and correctness.

I actually mean that, and all the evidence I need is in your existing code:

```
if (!StringUtils.isBlank(customerVO.getMaritalStatus())) {
    mstCustomer.setMaritalStatus(customerVO.getMaritalStatus());
}
if (StringUtils.isBlank(customerVO.getWeddingAnniversary())) {
    mstCustomer.setWeddingAnniversary(DateUtils.getDateFromString(customerVO.getWeddingAnniversary()));
}

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customerVO.getMotherTongue())) {
    mstCustomer.setMotherTongue(customerVO.getMotherTongue());
}
```

See the inconsistent conditionals? The first and last case make sense, but the wedding anniversary is only set if a wedding anniversary is *not* specified!

By copy pasting and mixing two different variants of the null handling logic, a bug was introduced, and, since nobody is patient enough to really read through this much repetition, never noticed.

In summary, don't duplicate code. Not even for something as seemingly trivial as null handling.

Comment: +1 for actually spotting a bug that other people including me had predicted if the code was not refactored. I agree with the statement that the actual way to refactor the code matters less than refactoring it in the first placec